# Can an F40T8 4ft ballast power an F36T8 2ft bulb?

Tags: electrical, fluorescent, ballast

I have some F36T8 2ft bulbs that I need to power, unfortunately the closest ballast I can locally find are rated for 4ft F40T8 bulbs. Can I still use them, or will it be a hazard?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Ballasts typically support a variety of tube sizes.  You've named one of the sizes this ballast supports, but that tells us nothing about the ballast or which other sizes it can or cannot support.  Can you identify the ballast part number or link the data sheet?

Comment: If it your lamp is not listed on the ballast or the information sheet that comes with it then you can't use it. Somewhere there is a listing of the approved lamps even if you have to find the spec sheet online.